# C++ function within a function?

Tags: c++, function, oop, methods

Hi I am working on a code and came by this c++ syntax. I am wondering what this exactly means.

```
function1(param1).function2(param2);
```

Does this represent function with in a function? Or something like trigger this function when the first one is over?

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/method-chaining.html

Comment: function2 must be a method from the returned object of function1.

Comment: Why is this legitimate question on C++ FAQ list, but downvoted on SO?

Comment: @SChepurin because there are too many people here now that think people shouldn't be allowed to ask basic questions as a way of learning something.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`function1` returns an object that has `function2` as a member function.

Answer (score 8):

```
function1(param1).function2(param2);
^returns an object    ^
                      | 
                      is a member function of returned object
```

Answer (score 8):

**`function1` returns an object that has a method named `function2`.**

Example `function1` may return an instance of a class looking like :

```
class MyClass
{
public:
//  ...
    void function2( int i ); // the return value and params are just for the example

//  ...
};

MyClass function1( Type paramName ); // example of prototype of function1
```